# Accessing data from SQLite cursor object (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

In my code, I execute an SQLite `SELECT` statement to query data in my database:

```
sqlite_obj = c.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE item_id = 2")
```

This will return all the data from the table row with `item_id = 2` as an SQLite cursor object. I try to access the data from the SQLite cursor object using the following code:

```
item_info = sqlite_obj[0][0]
```

This returns an error: `TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable` The following code, however, does work:

```
for item in sqlite_obj:
   item_info = item[0]
```

Why?

Comment: `cursor.execute` returns an _iterator_, which can't be accessed by index.  Each iteration of the iterator returns a row object which _can_ be accessed by index.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you. I understand now. Some helpful information I found on iterators: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp